Overleaf: please rerun biber
In my self-hosted instance of overleaf, my bibliography was not working and I had this error displayed: Please rerun biber, although all my references and .bib files were correct.
What could be the problem cause here?

Possibly https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/1081

good question! Hopefully this will save someone some time:
For my self-hosted overleaf instance, this needed to be done.
TLDR;

Log in to the container
docker exec -it sharelatex bash.
Inside, create a symlink to the biber executable
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/biber  /usr/local/bin/biber
Recompile your tex document
???
Profit


Hm. That means that the /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/ directory is not in the PATH, which will create a lot of other problems... probably the problem is elsewhere. Adding the overleaf tag could help to signal the question to people more knowledgable than me.

This answer can not be right, check your logs you are presumably not using the texlive 2024 tex at all but a linux system tex that you have packaged in the docker container as well as the upstream texlive 2024 which is installed but not in your path
